# using classic asp (obsolete I know but it is a start), how to plot multiple markers on a gmap and msaccess database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic, ms-access-2013, markers

I have this code that I recycled from the internet to extract lng lat data from ms access database and plot on a Google map. The map is showing and the coordinates are their but no markers are showing. the code I use shown below. Once again thank you

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org
      /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org
      /1999/xhtml">           
      <head> 

      <script src="http://maps.google.com
      /maps/apijs?key=AIzaSyCnkGeTzGO1_5_mCfAJZkQmG6RZOkyjGzE& sensor=false"
       type="text/javascript">

       </script>

       </head>   <body> <div id="map" style="width: 750px; height: 550px"></div> 

      <% @ Language="VBScript" %> 
      <% 
      Dim count, DataConn, rst, cmdTemp 
    Dim lng, lat 
    Dim countryArr(), songTitleArr(), songFileNameArr() 
    Dim ptLatArr(), ptLngArr() 
    Dim currLng, currLat 
    Dim theCtr  
     reDim countryArr(100) 
     reDim songTitleArr(100) 
      reDim songFileNameArr(100) 
      reDim ptLatArr(100) 
      reDim ptLngArr(100)  
     lat=-14.7793992 
     lng= 121.0236486  
    count = 0  
    Set DataConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dataconn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 
    DataConn.Open "D:/Webpage/data/philapig_b_V10.mdb"   
    Set cmdTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
    Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cmdTemp.CommandText = "SELECT Farmer_No, Surname, Firstname, Category, YCoordinate,
    XCoordinate, Type FROM FarmersDataWeb" 
    cmdTemp.CommandType = 1 
    Set cmdTemp.ActiveConnection = DataConn  
    rst.Open cmdTemp, , 1, 3  
    Do While NOT rst.EOF         
    countryArr(count)= rst("Farmer_No")
   songTitleArr(count)= rst("Category")        
   songFileNameArr(count)= rst("Type") 
   ptLatArr(count)= rst("XCoordinate")        
   ptLngArr(count)= rst("YCoordinate")       
   rst.MoveNext()        
   count = count + 1 
   loop  
   rst.Close 
    Set rst = Nothing DataConn.Close
    set DataConn = nothing %>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{  
    zoom: 10,      
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.7793992,121.0236486),     
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP          }); 
    function createMarker(point,ctr) {         
    var theMarker = new GMarker(point);      
    var infoText= ctryArr[ctr] + "<BR>" + sTitleArr[ctr] + "<a href=" + 
    sFileNameArr[ctr] + "><BR>Listen</a>";  

    GEvent.addListener(theMarker, "click", function()  
    {theMarker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoText);});     
    return theMarker; } 

    function setMarker(ctr) {  
    var pt = new GPoint(lngArr[ctr], latArr[ctr]);   
     var marker = createMarker(pt,ctr);

     map.addOverlay(marker); }
     var ctryArr=[]; var lngArr=[]; var latArr=[]; var sTitleArr=[]; var sFileNameArr=[]; var
     j=0;          
    <% for i = 0 to count - 1 %>    
    ctryArr[j]="<%=countryArr(i)%>";  
    sTitleArr[j]="<%=songTitleArr(i)%>";  
    sFileNameArr[j]="<%=songFileNameArr(i)%>";
    lngArr[j]="<%=ptLngArr(i)%>";      
    latArr[j]="<%=ptLatArr(i)%>";   
     j++;     
    <% next %> 
    for (k=0;k<ctryArr.length;k++) {   
      setMarker(k); }              

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your title says classic ASP, but your tags say ASP.NET. Which is it? Also, if this is classic ASP, you should not start a new project with it. Do it in ASP.NET instead.

Comment: Some of the JS code is Google Maps API v2 instead of v3, e.g. `GMarker`, `GPoint` and `GEvent`.  They aren't cross-compatible (API v2 no longer works in fact), and you need to rewrite it all to be strictly v3 code.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3

Comment: Thank you Duncan.. beginner's mistake! I updated the code to V3 but still it is not working... arghhh

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to work with the V3 Google Maps API. Replace the SCRIPT part with the following code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
        var map;

        function initializeGoogle() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.7793992,121.0236486)
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            <% for i = 0 to count - 1 %> 
                createMarker(<%=ptLatArr(i)%>, <%=ptLngArr(i)%>, ctryArr[ctr] + "<BR>" + sTitleArr[ctr] + "<a href=" + sFileNameArr[ctr] + "><BR>Listen</a>");
            <% next %> 
            };

        function createMarker(lat, lon, html) {
            var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                map: map,
            title: html
            });

            newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'mouseover', function() {
                this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initializeGoogle();
        });

    </script>
```